# An error occured during SSIS package execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have been executing the same SSIS package several times before the last week. It ran successfully without any issue. Execution time to complete is nearly around 20 mins to 2 hours depending on the data. Data is copied from Oracle to MSSQL.

Lately, it failed to run without any modification to the SSIS package. The below error is what I am getting...

```
Started:  10:07:56 AM
Error: 2021-12-13 10:11:00.56
   Code: 0xC020844B
   Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Destination [2]
   Description: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
End Error
Error: 2021-12-13 10:11:00.57
   Code: 0xC0047022
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
Error: 2021-12-13 10:11:03.20
   Code: 0xC02090F5
   Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Source [125]
   Description: The ADO NET Source was unable to process the data. Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0047020
End Error
Error: 2021-12-13 10:11:03.20
   Code: 0xC0047038
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ADO NET Source returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  10:07:56 AM
Finished: 10:11:03 AM
Elapsed:  186.265 seconds
```

I am unable to pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: *"A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server."* Suggests a connectivity error, or the server was shutdown/rebooted while the process was on going. Does one of the servers have a reboot scheduled around the time the package runs?

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I was able to ping the server successfully.  I am pretty sure the reboot will occur not many time per day, as I tried to test the SSIS package many time per day. Connectivity error - is there a way to check if that? I am not sure if ping cmd is good to check the connectivity issue?

Comment: Pinging checking if the host is available at that point in time. YOu have a process that is running for 20-120 minutes, according to your post, so that suggests that the connection goes down at some point during that time.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I did see that when I keep on pinging the server and ran the process. I see at some point I get request timed out. Not sure if this happened during my previous Test. Hopefully will take up the issue with the network team.